# Cordova won't open camera/select file android

Tags: android, html, cordova

Im working a small app that would access photos from a  phone, I follow the direction located on the cordova website http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File
I already installed the plugin but when I click the button to choose a photo nothing happens.

THis is how my config.xml looks:

```
<feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />
    </feature>
```

AndroidManifiest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a FileChooser plugin. The File plugin doesn't invoke any UI to let you choose  file. https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Filechooser+cordova

Comment: I try this and broked my app

Comment: From what I have tried. The 'don/FileChooser' one. It gives error when you pick a picture from the 'Recent' folder but works ok if you choose image from say the 'Gallary'. What you need is something like a FileChooser (since the File plugin doesn't actually provide you with one) though I haven't found one that works the way I like yet. Also I was on cordova 3.4.0 when I first tried the don/filechooser plugin on a Nexus 7.